# Cannot including files with GCC

Tags: c, gcc, build, compiler-errors

I am working in this project that requires me to use some software that was written a long time ago and is now open sourced and can be found at http://www.wotug.org/occam/compilers/oc/oc-src.tar.gz. The software is basically a compiler for Occam.

When I unpack the tar.gz I find a source folder that has a csh script to build the software.

```
#!/bin/csh -f
#   
# Quick build script for occam compiler and libraries
#   

# You will need to redefine these
set gccinclude = "/u/products/toolset/release/build/include/gcc"
set inmos_occam = /inmos/prod/d4205a

# These should be ok
set base_dir = $cwd
set path = ($inmos_occam/tools $base_dir/preocc $path)
setenv ISEARCH "$base_dir/libs/ $base_dir/include/ $gccinclude/"

set buildlibs = (arglib extlib tcofflib)
foreach buildlib ($buildlibs)
    echo --- $buildlib
    cd $buildlib
    make -f [Mm]akefile.s4 COMMON=$base_dir GCCINCLUDE=$gccinclude TLIB=
    cd ..
end 
... some other stuff...
```

I believe the lines:
    set gccinclude = "/u/products/toolset/release/build/include/gcc"
    set inmos_occam = /inmos/prod/d4205a
specify where the .h files are stored for the compilation process and the inmos_occam variable tells where I would like the final binary to be stored, so I changed them to:
    set gccinclude = "/usr/include"
    set inmos_occam = ./bin
The problem is that when I run the script I get the following errors:

```
--- arglib
gcc -I./ -nostdinc /usr/include ./arg.c -c -o arg.o -ansi -DSUN4
./arg.c:9:19: fatal error: ctype.h: No such file or directory
#include <ctype.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [arg.a] Error 1
--- extlib
gcc -c -msoft-float -Wall -ansi -pedantic -nostdinc /usr/include I/home/andres/Documents/T2015-Compiler/src/include -DGNU extconv.c
In file included from /home/andres/Documents/T2015-Compiler/src/include/extlib.h:8:0,
                 from extconv.c:1:
/home/andres/Documents/T2015-Compiler/src/include/imsstd.h:30:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
#include <stdio.h>
....and a lot more....
```

I dont know much about GCC, but I believe the problem is that the argument '-nostdinc' tells the compiler to not look in the standard include directories (where the files are in my ubuntu system) and that is why it is not working. However, I do not how to overwrite this behaviour. I would greatly appreciate help so that I can compile this, also if you believe this is not the cause of the problem, please do let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`-nostdinc` means that you are ignoring the standard include path, which I'm guessing you don't want. However I can see:

```
gcc -I./ -nostdinc /usr/include ./arg.c -c -o arg.o -ansi -DSUN4
```

`/usr/include` should be like `-I/usr/include` in order to include that to the include path.

Later you have

```
I/home/andres/Documents/T2015-Compiler/src/include
```

which should be

```
-I/home/andres/Documents/T2015-Compiler/src/include
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, about the 'I' and '-I' issue, I actually have it as '-I' is just that when I copied from the command line I made a mistake. I tried setting 'set gccinclude = "-I/usr/include"', this seems to have the effect I want, but I believe that there are some libraries actually missing from my machine such as 'sys/cdefs.h'

Comment: If there are libraries missing the linker should complain. If there are headers missing the compiler should complain.